# Ошибки при запуске простого приложения на JAVA.Вопрос новичка

Tags: java, веб-программирование, intellij-idea, tomcat, gradle

Начал изучение WEB'a на java и столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Было написано простое CRUD приложение типа "записная книжка". Сборка проекта осуществляется с помощью Gradl'a. При запуске приложения на Tomcat, на домашней странице не открывается ожидаемое окно, выдавая ошибку. Версия MySql - последняя, поэтому обновлять что-то, как того требуется в сообщении ошибки, не нужно.
Далее, при переходе в адресной строке на другую страницу, все работает, но при нажатии на "save", опять происходит выброс. 
Я не понимаю, почему так происходит. Вроде и все необходимые библиотеки подгружены, и web.xml настроен. Даже не знаю в какую сторону думать.
Скрины ошибок и примеры кода .xml файлов ниже по тексту.
Спасибо за уделенное внимание.

Spring configuration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="App"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home"/>

    <bean id="resolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>



</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>SpringMvcJdbcTemplate</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'


group 'Example4'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

ext {
    springVersion = '5.0.5.RELEASE'
    servletApiVersion = '3.0.1'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:$springVersion"
    compile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:$servletApiVersion"
    providedCompile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:$servletApiVersion"
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '4.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '4.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.10'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'


    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

[image: /(домашняя страничка)]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте Mysql 5.0. Дело в том, что простые приложения написанные кем-то работают только в созданной ими среде. При сборке необходимо проверить версии библиотек, которые должны быть совместимы с используемым ПО. Неверные версии часто приводят к подобного рода ошибкам.